# getting number of time user has logged in

Tags: django, django-models

Hi this is probably a duplicate question but I cant find the answer that I need.

I have a login model

```
class Login(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date    = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want get the number of time's each user has logged in against one entry for that user.

I've tried

```
map(lambda x:{'name': x.user, 'count': x.login_count}, Login.objects.all().order_by('user').annotate(login_count=Count('user')))
```

However I get a list back containing every entry with a value of 1 against login_count.
e.g if bill has logged in 60 time's I get 60 list items for bill with a value of 1 against each items login_count what I want is 1 list item for bill with a value of 60 against login_count.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried without the order_by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier if you attack it from the User object:

```
login_stats = User.objects.annotate(num_logins=Count("login")).order_by("-num_logins")
for l in login_stats:
    print "User %s logged in %i times" % (l, l.num_logins)
```